# What does the C# operator => mean?

Tags: c#, operators

Answers to a recent post (Any chances to imitate times() Ruby method in C#?) use the **=>** operator in the usage examples.  What does this operator do?  I can't locate it in my C# book, and it is hard to search for symbols like this online.  (I couldn't find it.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the '=>' syntax in C# mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290061/what-does-the-syntax-in-c-sharp-mean)

Answer (score 15):

It's not really an operator as such, it's part of the syntax for lambda expressions. In particular => is the bit which separates the parameters from the body of the lambda expression.

Does your book cover C# 3.0? If not, it won't include lambda expressions. If it does, it should really cover them! Hopefully with the right terminology, you'll be able to find it in the TOC or index.

EDIT: A bit more information: A lambda expression is a piece of syntactic sugar to either create an instance of a delegate *or* an expression tree (the latter being new to .NET 3.5). Lambda expressions almost entirely replace anonymous methods (from C# 2.0) although they don't support the notion of "I don't care about the parameters" in the way that anonymous methods do.

Comment: Ah, my book does not cover C#3.0, so no wonder I couldn't locate it!

Comment: Can I ask you what you mean with `"I don't care about the parameters" in the way that anonymous methods do.`? Thanks!

Comment: @xanatos: For example, to create an `EventHandler` which doesn't use the sender or args, you can use `delegate { Console.WriteLine("Called"); }` without specifying a parameter list at all. That's convertible to *any* delegate type with a return type of void and all "in" parameters.

Answer (score 4):

A lambda expression is an anonymous function that can contain expressions and statements, and can be used to create delegates or expression tree types.

All lambda expressions use the lambda operator =>, which is read as "goes to". The left side of the lambda operator specifies the input parameters (if any) and the right side holds the expression or statement block

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The => token is called the **lambda operator**.

It is used in lambda expressions to separate the input variables on the left side from the lambda body on the right side.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

That will be for a lambda expression:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

An example is here:

```
MyControl.OnMouseDown += (sender, e) =>
{
  // Do something in the mouse down event
};
```

Here I have created a lambda expression event delegate. It basically saves me from having to create a separate function for it in the class.