# Lambda - Linq Convert

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I know have this simple lambda query`(not sure if this one called a query)`

```
var person = db.People.Where(a => a.PersonId == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

I have a question because i don't know anything about lambda. What is the purpose of `=>` and what is the value of that in linq if it is converted to linq?.

For my basic knowledge this might the converted linq query

```
var person = (from p in db.Person where p.PersonId == id select p).FirstOrDefault();
```

right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the '=>' syntax in C# mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290061/what-does-the-syntax-in-c-sharp-mean)

Comment: Both are linq. The top is called method syntax while the bottom is called query syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `=>`, which can be read as *maps to* or *is mapped* to belongs to the syntax of labda expressions. Informally the syntax of lambda expressions is

```
(arg_1, arg_2, ..., arg_n) => rhs,
```

where `(arg-1, arg_2, ..., arg_n)` is the list of arguments; if there is one argument, the list `(arg1)` can be abbreviated to `arg1`. `rhs` is either an expression of the desired return type, such as in

```
x => x * x
```

or a compound statement returning the desired type as follows.

```
x =>
{
    return x * x;
}
```

The arguments and return type of the lambda expression are not explicitly defined but deduced at compile time. In total,

```
a => a.PersonId == id
```

defines function which maps a person `a` to a boolean value which is generated by evaluating `a.PersonId == id`, which means that the return value is `true` if and only if the person's `PersonId` is equal to `id`.

Answer (score 0):

The => is the lambda operator, and is part of the syntax for lambda expressions.

On the left of the => are the input parameters for the expression on the right of =>

```
a=> a.PersonId == id
```

is like a function that takes a person object and an Id and returns a boolean, i.e.

```
bool CheckIfIdIsEqual(Person a, int id) {
     return a.PersonId == id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. The expressions where we use  `=>` operator are called lambda expressions.

In the lambda calculus, we describe these patterns as tiny functions. In the C# language, we use lambda functions and the => operator to transform data.

```
 var person = db.People.Where(a => a.PersonId == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

In the above code, we access all the values or data from `db.People` using the variable `a`

For more information you can refer:

[1.Expression Lambdas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb397687.aspx)

[2.C Sharp Lambda Expression](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/csharp/LOUM180612-C-Sharp-Lamda-Expression.html)

[3.Lambda Expression](http://www.dotnetperls.com/lambda)