# Struggling to understand LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq

Below is my code I'm working with in C#. I understand it's finding the mode for my set of data, but what I'm confused on is the `GroupBy(value => value)` and what exactly the `=>` does because I can change value to anything and it still works. I would like to be able to use LINQ, I just need a deeper understanding as far as these parameters go.

```
static double Mode()
{
  double mode = valueArray.GroupBy(value => value)
        .OrderByDescending(value => value.Count())
        .First()
        .Key;
  return mode;
}
```

Comment: The => indicates a lambda. You should read the relevant documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx.

Comment: oh awesome thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the '=>' syntax in C# mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290061/what-does-the-syntax-in-c-sharp-mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's dissect different parts of your `Linq Query`. Here each call's result / output act as the  Input for the next call to process the data

1. `valueArray.GroupBy(value => value)`

`GroupBy` here has a same usage as in Sql, it leads to result in the format `IEnumerable<IGrouping<Key,Value>>`, `lambda =>` is a glue, where it provides each an every element in the collection `valueArray` for processing. Only strange part is you take the whole object as a `Key`, so the Result will be same `object as key and value` in this case. In case, if it's a `custom class / reference type and not primitive type`, then override `Equals` and `GetHashcode` methods for the correct operation, else it will do reference comparison of the objects. Your case key seems to be `double - primitive type`, which is fine

2. `OrderByDescending(value => value.Count())`

This shall be simple, take the `Count` of the `IGrouping elements`, for each `Grouping` and arrange in the `descending` order. Result is `IOrderedEnumerable<IGrouping<Key,Value>>`, which are arranged by the grouped elements `Count`

3. `First()`

Take `First` element with maximum count value i.e Only one `IGrouping<Key,Value>` is selected

4. `Key`

Take the Key of the `First` element, and return as a `result`