# What does x=>(int)x - 48 mean when you add a number to a digit array?

Tags: c#, arrays, integer, toarray

so im taking number input and the im trying to add each digit to an array of int without using any loop

here i got an answer

```
int[] fNum = Array.ConvertAll(num.ToString().ToArray(),x=>(int)x - 48);
```

I understand until .toarray(), but I do not understand why it takes a new variable x and the => (int)x - 48.

Could anyone explain this to me?

Comment: It's a lambda expression. There's lots of information around about lambda expressions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the '=>' syntax in C# mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290061/what-does-the-syntax-in-c-sharp-mean)

Comment: `(int)x` => convert this character from the string to it's unicode value as an integer. Note that `Array.ConvertAll` must have a loop inside it, so your program still has a loop.

Comment: Side note: it should have been written as `letter => letter - '0'` and now the meaning is clear: turning characters ascii codes of `'0'..'9'` into corresponding integer values `0..9`

Comment: Side note: `int[] fNum = num.ToString().Select(letter => letter - '0').ToArray();` seems to be more readable

Answer (score 2):

Because the asci value of 0 is 48 and for 1 it is 49. so to get the char value 1 you need to do 49 - 48 which is equal to 1 and similarly for other numbers.

you should also look in to the documentation of [Array.ConvertAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.convertall?view=net-7.0).

It clearly explains the second parameter,

> A Converter<TInput,TOutput> that converts each element from one type
> to another type.

You can also refer to this declaration in the Array class.

[image]

Also, have a look to understand [lambda operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290061/what-does-the-syntax-in-c-sharp-mean) and the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions).

Comment: can you explain all of this ,x=>(int)x - 48

Comment: its lambda operator you can explorer it.

Comment: An image of code? Can you paste the code itself?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman it's a generic code from the framework, so I posted it as an image. OP can easily find it. it's more like a comment not the implementation

Comment: @VasantRaval have a courtesy to accept the answer if it has really helped you

Answer (score 1):

> without using any loop

Well, I might have a surpise for you.

> a new variable x

`ConvertAll` is actually a loop under the hood. It iterates through the collection. `x` represents an item in the collection.

> `x=>(int)x - 48`

For each item x in the collection, cast it to an int and subtract 48.

This syntax is a [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions).

Comment: No. => means: with this item x and the lefthand side of the arrow we are going to perform the action on the righthand side of the arrow.

Answer (score 0):

```
num.ToString().ToArray(),x=>(int)x - 48
```

This code is process of dividing a string filled with numbers into an array of characters, converting CHAR-type characters into ASCII values, and converting them into Int values.

The letter '5' of the CHAR type is an ASCII value of 53 and must be -48 to convert it to a INT type value 5.