# Is the use of lamda operator for the following method body just syntactic sugar?

Tags: c#, lambda

Are these two method declarations identical once compiled?

(1)

```
public void MyMethod() => ... ;
```

(2)

```
public void MyMethod()
{
...
}
```

If not is there a penalty incurred for using the shorter first syntax?

Comment: It is just sugar syntax and nothing more.

Comment: sharp lab is always a good address for such questions: https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYZQAs6AsgBQCUhxBSxLmcAnNQEQAuApgGceXWgG4GRAL4T0MtJgqUYddAF4AfG069BwscklA===

Comment: @SomeBody - thanks for that brilliant link .  Good to know for future. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the '=>' syntax in C# mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290061/what-does-the-syntax-in-c-sharp-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, those are identical. You can see this by using SharpLab which will show you the intermediate code that is generated. So this:

```
public class C {
    public void MyMethod1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello");
    }
    
    public void MyMethod2() => Console.WriteLine("hello");
}
```

Will convert to this:

```
public class C
{
    public void MyMethod1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello");
    }

    public void MyMethod2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello");
    }
}
```

Example: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGAzAATakDCpA3oaQ+WRiqQLICebMALgBYQAJjgAUASnqM6BRrPI4AnCIBEfGABt1EZWIDckhgF8DpEyXKtO3fkKzjSAXgB88pao1ad+goaA