# Inheritance - is it possible to 'force' variable values relative to the derived class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, properties, member

I am trying to create a simple model. A vehicle can only ever have 1 `VehicleType`, and a `VehicleType` is a `Vehicle`. As such I have created a base class `Vehicle`, and three derived classes `Bike`, `Car`, and `Truck`.

When I create the derived classes, is there anyway that I can force certain variables to always be the same for that class and **not rely purely on the constructor**? E.g., `numberOfWheels` is always going to be 2 for a bike, and 4 for a car.. Is there anyway I can force declare that, or do I always have to declare them in the constructor? If I had multiple variables specific to that class, it just seems counter-intuitive to have to declare them individually and risk errors, when I can't help but think it would be so much easier to do it dynamically.

I have read the [proposed duplicate](/q/53091380), and I don't see how this answers the question. I am happy to be corrected, but please explain why - The duplicate question/answer only makes the base property read-only and would not solve my original question regarding variables that are common between all children and parent, but different for each class.  I.e., all vehicles have wheels, however all bicycles only have 2 wheels; cars have 2, tricycles have 3, etc..

I am pretty new to this and would appreciate an answer in simple terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the site. I think this is a great question and it illustrates some of the most powerful features of object oriented programming. And no you don't have to rely on the constructor.

`abstract` classes and properties can be used to accomplish what you're looking for. To give a concise code example:

```
public enum VehicleType
{
    Car,
    Truck,
    Bike
}

public abstract class Vehicle
{
    public abstract VehicleType Type { get; }
    public abstract int NumberOfWheels { get; }
}

public class Car : Vehicle
{
    public sealed override VehicleType Type => VehicleType.Car;
    public sealed override int NumberOfWheels => 4;

    // Properties and methods specific to Car
}

public class Bike: Vehicle
{
    public sealed override VehicleType Type => VehicleType.Bike;
    public sealed override int NumberOfWheels => 2;

    // Other properties and methods specific to Bike
}

// etc.
```

`abstract` means the derived classes must implement the missing member by overriding it. So for each subclass of `Vehicle`, in this example, you are forced to override `Type` and return one of the `VehicleType` values, and thus don't have to rely on the constructor (or a member that could be inadvertently changed elsewhere).

Adding the `sealed` keyword also prevents subsequent subclasses of the individual vehicles from changing that property, so for example any class derived from Car (Sedan, Coupe, Roadster, etc) will always have 4 wheels.

Comment: Smashing!

I haven't played with this yet (I'm sat with a flask of tea reading things) but it looks exactly like what I was getting at, THANK YOU for the explanation!!
Online lessons are great and all, but there is only so far they can go. There really is no substitute for having someone explain things!

Comment: I'm experimenting with your solution :-) Thanks. Quick question, though, what is '=>' is that LINQ? I've heard of LINQ and it's on my list of things to read about / learn.

If not, what is it?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Hi @Phil you're more than welcome (and sorry about all the "meta" discussion last night. :)) The `=>` notation is just shorthand for `{ get { return XXX; } }`. This may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290061/what-does-the-syntax-in-c-sharp-mean. It pops up in LINQ, but also in many other places.

Comment: Ahha! I didn't even realise that that was a 'thing'. Done. Thank you for the guidance. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Phil If you aren't interested in having immutable properties, and are perfectly okay with your base class having implementations in which the properties are mutable and allowed to change over time for each object, then why did you ask that in your question?  You seemed to make a point in the question about how vehicles type and number of wheels needs to be fixed but apparently that requirement is no longer true for you?

Comment: @Servy Hi there. I just had to just look up what you mean by immutable :-) Good to know! Thank you. Perhaps I don't fully understand yet how to articulate my questions to people who are native speakers, but basically I wanted to create some new objects of an inherited class without having to repeat things that would ALWAYS be constant in the constructor. Again, not sure if I have explained myself very well, but I've just posted how I implemented the advice given. Hopefully this picture paints a 1000 words.
I'm basically trying to learn the 'right' thing to do? Is this not safe? Cheers :-) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the [answer and comments from EmporerEto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78222465/11810933), this is how I implemented it:

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Vehicle> VehicleList = new List<Vehicle>();

        new Car(1, "Renault", VehicleList);
        new Truck(2, "Ford", VehicleList);

        foreach (Vehicle v in VehicleList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ID:{v.Id}, Type:{v.VehicleType}, Manufacturer:{v.Manufacturer}, Number of wheels:{v.NumberOfWheels}");
        }
    }


    public enum VehicleType
    {
        Car,
        Bike,
        Truck
    }


    public abstract class Vehicle
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public abstract int NumberOfWheels { get; }
        public abstract VehicleType VehicleType { get; }


        public Vehicle(int id, string manufacturer, List<Vehicle> vehicles)
        {
            Id = id;
            Manufacturer = manufacturer;
            vehicles.Add(this);
        }
    }


    public class Truck : Vehicle
    {
        public sealed override int NumberOfWheels => 12;
        public sealed override VehicleType VehicleType => VehicleType.Truck;

        public Truck(int id, String manufacturer, List<Vehicle> vehicles)
            : base(id, manufacturer, vehicles)
        {
        }
    }


    public class Car : Vehicle
    {
        public sealed override int NumberOfWheels => 4;
        public sealed override VehicleType VehicleType => VehicleType.Car;

        public Car(int id, string manufacturer, List<Vehicle> vehicles)
            : base(id, manufacturer, vehicles)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice. And just for illustration's sake, you could take it one step further, and add `virtual int NumberOfDoors` to `Car` (not `abstract` and not `sealed`), and give it a default implementation of `=> 4`. Then you could add a `Coupe` class, and do a `sealed override` to `=> 2`. In other words cars by default have 4 doors, but coupes are an exception so they have 2 and only 2. This sort of thing is what makes C# such a great language for Unity or anything else that requires modelling real world objects.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).